# How to limit image size in Lightbox 2

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox2

I'm using [`Lightbox 2`](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). I'd like to know how to limit the image size to `800px`?

I tried to edit tje image size in CSS directly, however this resulted in the outer container still keeping its old size...

Comment: Hi, i suggest you read the faq --> http://stackoverflow.com/faq and show us some code (css, html)

Comment: Well, I haven't changed lot of stuff. Basically, I only added this line `.lb-image {
  width: 800px;
}`

Comment: Please read this post, it explains exactly what you are looking for http://slopjong.de/2013/04/02/lightbox2-limit-the-max-image-size/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to stop expanding after 800px in width. Try `.lb-image { max-width: 800px }` instead.